# Cardview is displaying in second fragment too

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a cardview and a button in my content_main.xml , if the user press the button , it should show the the fragment (named radio fragment), when i do that cardview is still showing in the radio fragment(fragment name)

*i want to hide the cardview and button and show the fragment, when the user press the button*

**here is my content main**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/Relative"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.radioplanet.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">




<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:cardElevation="10dp" >


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**here is the fragment_radio.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.radioplanet.Radio">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"


    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:animationResolution="@integer/abc_max_action_buttons"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

**this is the button function in main activity**

```
  Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Radio radio=new Radio();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
             manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Relative, radio,radio.getTag()).commit();

        }
    });
}
```

any one can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CardView` and `Button` is showing because both are elevated above the `RelativeLayout`.

So when you set fragment on `RelativeLayout`, it is placed under those views.

One solution will be to cover the `cardview` and `button` inside a layout and hide the layout when showing fragment, and unhide it on the reverse process.

Comment: Button is not showing in the fragment, only cardview

Comment: ok. i think if you run on android ver > 5.0, both will be visible

Comment: Now what to do, if if i add the visibility gone option in the button function.. is that fine?

Comment: no problem in hiding a view which is not needed. Instead of hiding individually all views, add it to a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and hide that layout as i suggested

Comment: Yup... I am gonna hide both. Coz i donno the other way

Answer (score 4):

Use FrameLayout as a root layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.radioplanet.Radio">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:animationResolution="@integer/abc_max_action_buttons"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And then replace your fragment using this id:R.id.container

Comment: No see my main activity java code, i was replacing the total layout content_main i named as relative

Comment: Then use FrameLayout as a root Layout and put your RelativeLayout inside it.And use FrameLayout as a container

Comment: Working but apbar is gone, became full screen

Answer (score 1):

try adding a background to your `Relativelayout`:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/Relative"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?android:windowBackground"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.radioplanet.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
```

if that's not work;
try:

```
manager.beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, radio,radio.getTag()).commit();
```

`android.R.id.content` gives you the root element of a view,

Comment: It works but, the app bar is not there in the second fragment

Comment: you are trying which option? and is you app bar is within `RealtiveLayout`

Comment: It becoming full screen when i use Android.r.id.content

Comment: Cardview Has elevation so it is still visilbe event if you add fragment over it. Try adding not only background but elevation too.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you do not replace the views inside the container.
The documentation for `replace()` says:

> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling `remove(Fragment)` for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then `add(int, Fragment, String)` with the same arguments given here.

I don't think that there is an existing fragment that you are replacing. 
You can work around this by either hiding both the `CardView` and the `Button` or setting a background on your fragment should also work.